# How do I get my pre-conda environment back?

Tags: python, anaconda

I had a Python 2.7 installation running on my Ubuntu machine then wanted to do some development on an existing Python package.

I installed Miniconda and added an environment and now have:

```
> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
pandas_dev               /foobar/miniconda/envs/pandas_dev
root                  *  /foobar/miniconda
```

But although my `root` environment is currently active, I *don't* have access to my old Python installation via `python`:

```
> python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>>
```

But when I run IPython, I *do* have my old installation:

```
> ipython
iPython 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

How can I get `python` to see the same environment as `ipython` currently does?

My `.bashrc` contains the following line:

```
# added by Miniconda 3.10.1 installer
export PATH="/home/rob/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Clearly I could just remove this, but that doesn't seem like a very sustainable solution. (What if I want to use my `pandas_dev` environment again?)

Comment: This may interest you: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/813. In the comments there's a dirty hack that uses an empty directory as a conda environment.

Comment: Ah, what a mess! I just commented out the line in my `.bashrc` in the end, which worked just fine.